# Create a param in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a class which creates a user and tests to see if the user is able to access multiple sites given the user criteria. I want to be able to create a new param if the user is a member of school. So I say:

```
  if user.memberships.include?(school)
    params[:current_school_member] = true
  end
```

The logic is correct, in that if the user is a school member, the method is accessed. I also have a list of params I can see, but get the error message:

`undefined local variable or method 'params'`

How can I create the param `current_school_member` and set value to true? The odd part is when I've tried this with `binding.pry` it works.

Thanks

Comment: Params comes from the view. Please check your vieWS for this issue. And let us know your view code.

Comment: where are you accessing the `params`? controller or model?

Comment: I want to set a param so that the controller can state if !params[: current_school_member] ....

Comment: This method has to be written in your controller since params isn't available in your model.

Comment: Probably be easier to take the logic away from params and put it into the controller or into the view. In the former case, you culd have the controller look up the user from a session id or a param, then determine if s/he has access, and show or re-route depending. The alternative would be in the view, to have some conditional code to show only links to schools where the user has a membership / access.

Comment: are you redirecting from one action to another with params ? `params` is accessible when you make a request to an action on a controller .. if you're using params as a hash data variable somewhere else on a method .. you need to define it before assigning values to it. `params = {}`

Comment: Need More Info about this "class" to Provide an answer